# Sidechained shifting Convolution?

Tags: convolution, convolution-reverb, logic

Hi all,

I'm trying to create a plugin in logic in which the decay of a piano uncovers prerecorded whispers. What's the best workflow to create this? Convolution reverb kind of gets me half way there,but I'm dissatisfied that with every note, the same pattern of whispers is created. Is there a way to create a kind of shifting\sidechained IR?

maybe there's a better solution? Like a sidechained gate on the whispers with some kind of delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you could try a vocoder, or better yet, this is what I would experiment with.

Set up a long track with whispers and get your whole atmosphere going, right? so on its own it's just a crazy track of whispers and delays and mess.

Then, set up your other track which would be the "trigger" for lack of better wording. On your whisper track, set up a noise gate plug in with the side chain as the piano track. You will have to set up a bus or send from your piano track to show the output, but as you adjust the settings for the noise gate for attack and release, you should have the "reverb" effect, but it will trigger along with your track.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I actually was just about to write a post as I ended up figuring it out on my own and did something very similar. I just added a reverb with a bit of swell to it to round things out and routed the trigger track with a send to my 'whisper bus' so I can automate when I want the effect to be active. 